# How can I add a custom header only on redirects

Tags: nginx

I want to change the cache control header when there's an HTTP redirect related code (30x).

How can I check the response's HTTP code to see if I should run `add_header`

Comment: Great question!  I'm amazed it got so little attention!

Answer (score 3):

The [following](//github.com/cnst/StackOverflow.cnst.nginx.conf/blob/master/sf.760729.add_header-on-all-redirects.nginx.conf) should work:

```
server {
    listen 60729;
    error_page 301 @301;
    return 301 http://example.su/test;
    location @301 {
        add_header X-Header value;
        return 301 $sent_http_location;
    }
}
```

Here's the confirmation:

```
%curl -v localhost:60729 | & fgrep \
    -e HTTP/ -e X-Header -e Location -e title | sed 's#^#\t#g'
> GET / HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://example.su/test
< X-Header: value
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
```

Note that each part of the config is quite important:

- the [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/r/error_page) directive effectively provides a very neat exception handling capabilities to nginx;
- without `return 301` within `location @301`, nginx will try to serve the requisite file from the filesystem; this will likely result in a `404`, so, you'll get a `404` page;  note that the `Location` header would still be preserved, but the `X-Header` will be missing from a [`404 Not Found`](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_special_response.c#ngx_http_error_404_page) page, because, as per the documentation of the [`add_header`](http://nginx.org/r/add_header) directive, it doesn't let you add headers to error pages;
- with a plain `return 301;` within `location @301`, you will effectively clear out the `Location`, so, your `Location` would be empty; thus you have to use [`$sent_http_`](http://nginx.org/r/$sent_http_) to preserve the current value.

If you want to try out my POC MVP as above, you can find the full config in [my GitHub](http://cnst.su/GitHub) at https://github.com/cnst/StackOverflow.cnst.nginx.conf.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you're doing the redirects within nginx. You'll have to build Nginx with the headers_more module which is pretty easy - see my [Nginx tutorial here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/).

```
 location /match/ {
   add_header HEADER_NAME "header value";
   return 301 https://example.com;
 }
```

If you're proxying through to an application that's returning redirects then it would be a little more complex, probably involving IF statements. IF in nginx doesn't always work as you expect, so you may be best off changing the application in that case.